# Mean Value Theorem H

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and let $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Show that there exists a $c\in (a,b)$ such that $$f'(c)=f(c)g'(c)$$

I've been stumped on this for hours. I attempted to define $$h(x)=f(x)-f(c)g(x)$$ and show that $h'(c)$ is $0$ without success.

Comment: what is the condition on $g$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Motivation:** Heuristically you need $\frac{f'}{f}(c)=g'(c)$ or $\ln(f)'(c)=g'(c)$. This would suggest to define $h(x) =\ln (f(x))-g(x)$ and study it. But, we cannot work with $\ln f$, as $f$ is zero.

Define instead $e^{h(x)}$ to eliminate the log, and hence the issue.

**Solution**

Let $h(x) =\frac{f(x)}{e^{g(x)}}$. Apply the Rolle Theorem.

Comment: well done. nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f(a) = f(b), g(a) = g(b)$. Consider $h(x) = \ln f(x) - g(x) \to h(a) = h(b) \to \exists c \in (a,b), h'(c) = 0 \to f'(c) = f(c)g'(c)$

Comment: The problem is that $h(a), h(b)$ are undefined. And if $f$ is negative, $h$ is not defined at any point....